# Need help writing test case for this code

Tags: python, testing

How to write test case for this code without using any external library?

Python program to reverse string of the input while keeping the special characters at the same place

```
    #Returns true if x is an alphabetic character, false otherwise
    def isAlphabet(x):
        return x.isalpha()

    def reverse_string(input_str):
        LIST = toList(input_str)

        #Initialize left and right pointers
        r = len(LIST) - 1
        l = 0

        #Traverse LIST from both ends until 'l' and 'r'
        while l < r:


            #Ignore special characters
            if not isAlphabet(LIST[l]):
                l += 1
            elif not isAlphabet(LIST[r]):
                r -= 1

            #Both LIST[l] and LIST[r] are not special 
            else:
                LIST[l], LIST[r] = swap(LIST[l], LIST[r])
                l += 1
                r -= 1

        return toString(LIST)

    # Utility functions 
    def toList(input_str): 
        List = [] 
        for i in input_str: 
            List.append(i) 
        return List

    def toString(List): 
        return ''.join(List) 

    def swap(a, b): 
        return b, a 

    # Driver code 
    input_str = "adfc_#sin*"
    print "Input string: " + input_str
    input_str = reverse_string(input_str) 
    print "Output string: " + input_str


    input_str = "hon()lo&"
    print "Input string: " + input_str
    input_str = reverse_string(input_str) 
    print "Output string: " + input_str
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It should not be too hard to think of some input strings, perform the algorithm by hand, and put these input/output tuples into your test

Comment: I have only written the program. I am new to unit testing. Can you give me an example on how to work around with this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Here you can ① post your code (as a [mcve]), ② describe what you observe it does (with which input), and ③ describe what you expect to observe instead.  This results in a clear question which can be answered.  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more about this.

Comment: I would direct you to the Python builtin [unit testing framework](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html). It's very handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
input_str = "1234#as"
wanted_output = "sa#4321"

cur_output = reverse_string(input_str)

print("Input: ", input_str, "Output OK?", cur_output==wanted_output)
```

or this way:

```py
assert cur_output==wanted_output
```

Comment: special character is not at same position

Comment: Sorry! I just wanted to show the way of comparing an expected result with an actual result.